# VM Networking and Subnetting

Tags: linux, windows, networking, routing, subnet

### Some background:

I'm attempting to set up a pentesting network with a handful of virtual machines for the SANS 560 (Network Penetration Testing and Ethical Hacking) course, but I'm having an issue with the network configuration.

To paint a picture of the network (at least how it's intended to be):

- My home router (connected to the internet, also the gateway for all other machines on the network) IP is `192.168.0.1/24`, with all other machines on the network in the `255.255.255.0` subnet
- As per the course notes, I should be setting up all my virtual machines with bridged adapters on the `10.10.X.X/16` subnet - with Linux machines on `10.10.75.X/16`, Windows guest machines on `10.10.76.X/16`, and my "host" (also a VM running Windows) machine on `10.10.78.1/16`

### My question:

How (assuming it's possible) do I configure my host machine (with new new IP `10.10.78.1/16`) to be able to talk to the other guest machines (Virtual machines) while also being able to connect to the internet?

I've tried setting up a static route to use the new IP as the gateway (seeing as the router is on a different subnet):
`route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0  10.10.78.1` (`192.168.0.0` is the destination, obviously the mask is `255.255.255.0`, and the gateway is `10.10.78.1`) - it didn't work (all I get is `Destination Host Unreachable`)

Do I need to have two interfaces on this Windows machine (i.e. one configured as `10.10.78.1/16` to talk to the other VMs, and another configured as `192.168.0.X/24` to access the internet) to make this configuration possible?

I understand it's not how a network would be set up typically, so please let me know if you need me to clarify or provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried setting up a static route to use the new IP as the gateway (seeing as the router is on a different subnet): route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0  10.10.78.1

Telling a machine to use *itself* as a gateway makes no sense.

Especially in this case, 192.168.0.0/24 is "on-link" and so by definition *doesn't* use a gateway. Instead, you need to specify the *interface* (using `if <index>`, IIRC).

However, in your situation I don't think that manually adding a route is a good solution. Instead, just assign *both* IP addresses, `192.168.0.x/24` *and* `10.0.76.x/16`, to the host machine. (Yes, Windows lets you do that.)

> Do I need to have two interfaces on this Windows machine (i.e. one configured as 10.10.78.1/16 to talk to the other VMs, and another configured as 192.168.0.X/24 to access the internet) to make this configuration possible?

Not technically required, but... you *are* configuring two networks, so yes, having two interfaces would be a better fit – one per subnet.

The second interface can be a virtual one, e.g. created using VMware's "host-only networking" function, or you can install "Microsoft Loopback Adapter."

Comment: Ok, so I tried what I think you're telling me to do. On my Windows VM (hosted on a Windows machine `192.168.0.10/24`), I now have two adapters; one bridged (`192.168.0.11/24` with gateway `192.168.0.1`), and one host-only (`10.10.78.1/16` with no gateway set as I guess routes to other VMs on the same host with IP's of `10.10.x.x/16` are on-link?). I still get `Destination host unreachable` when pinging the following addresses: `192.168.0.10` (host machine), `192.168.0.1` (internet gateway), `8.8.8.8` (google DNS). I'm guessing since I can't get to the host machine, that's where the issue is.

Comment: The other issue is that they recommend using bridged adapters for each VM, so going with the host-only adapter assigned as `10.10.78.1` explicitly contradicts that directive.